# How can I put the values into a array in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I put these input values into an array? When I try it with `.append()` or `.push()` it does not show the values in the Chrome console...

```
$("#anzahlProzesse").change(function () {
    let counter = $('#anzahlProzesse').val();
    for (let i = 1; i <= counter; i++) {
        let row3 = $("<tr><td>" + i + "</td><td>" + "<input type='number' id='prozess" + i + "'></input>" + "</td><tr>");
        $("#sjftable").append(row3);
    }
    $("#berechnen").show();
});
```

This should be done after clicking the `#berechnen` button:

```
$("#berechnen").click(function () {
    let cpuLaufzeit = [];
    let ankunftszeit = [];
    let anzahlProzesse = $('#anzahlProzesse').val();
    for (let i = 1; i <= anzahlProzesse; i++) {
        let cpu = $("*prozess" + i).val();
        cpuLaufzeit.push(cpu);
    }
    console.log(cpuLaufzeit);
}
```

Comment: You must add an MCVE http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. Please note that non-English variable names are generally a really bad idea.

Comment: add html code also

Comment: `$("*prozess" + i)` should be `$("#prozess" + i)`

Comment: I do not understand what exactly you what to do. Please check the loop. It seems you have a problem  here.Check the value anzahlProzesse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<input type='text' id="anzahlProzesse" ></input>

$("#anzahlProzesse").change(function () {
    let counter = $('#anzahlProzesse').val();
    var myarray = new Array();
     myarray.push(counter);
     console.log(myarray);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the html code for that:

```
<h4>Wieviele Prozesse soll es sein?</h4>
      <div class="input-group">
        <input type="number" id="anzahlProzesse" class="form-control" placeholder="Anzahl an Prozessen"
          aria-describedby="groessen-addon2">
      </div>
    </p>
    <br>
    <br>
    <p>
      <table class="table table-striped" id="sjftable">
        <tr>
          <th>Prozess</th>
          <th>CPU-Laufzeit</th>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <table class="table table-striped" id="fcfstable">
        <tr>
          <th>Prozess</th>
          <th>CPU-Laufzeit</th>
          <th>Ankunftszeit</th>
        </tr>
      </table>
```

After entering the values into that created tables, it should take the values and put them into an array.

Comment: Edit that into the question instead of adding an answer!